# Gesture recognizers and auto-layout in iOS6, scaling from the center

Tags: ios, xcode, cgaffinetransform, autolayout, cgaffinetransformscale

This gesture recognizer code below, which normally would scale a view from the center, does not when auto-layout is enabled in iOS6. The view seems to scale from it's origin when auto layout is enabled. Other affine transformations (particularly scale and rotate) are also not working as I expected.

Anyone have this issue, or can enlighten me to the right way to handle this?

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;  
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am really stuck on this issue. Please comment.

Comment: @HenryHarris not sure because I stopped trying to use auto-layout, but I believe that if you create the view in question via code, and don't add constraints, that the gesture recognizer may perform as expected.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to use storyboards and cannot turn auto-layout off for one part of my storyboard without getting this error, `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`

Comment: @HenryHarris strange... I thought that was an autoLayout error, ie you would get it if AL was ON. In any case you should be able to resolve that, but I never use AL myself as of now. I always manually disable it when I start a project.

Comment: @Mrwolfy : hey. any solution to this issue?????

Comment: @coder1010 yeah, disable auto-layout. I think when I wrote this I was trying to integrate auto layout into my devs, at this point I have abandoned it as it just seems to be too complex. I may revisit it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Autolayout you should edit your constraints because transforms and constraints can be conflicting... I had the same problem and [this](https://speakerdeck.com/wwdcman/session-228-best-practices-for-mastering-auto-layout/) session at WWDC helped me a lot. Take a look at the Video beginning at 30:35